# AWS EC2 - Deployment rails/passenger/nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to deploy to an AWS EC2 staging instance.

I'm following these instructions:

http://alexbachuk.com/launch-rails-4-application-with-passenger-and-nginx/

When I create a test app and point to it via my local host, AWS successfully recognises the test page.

When I change the nginx conf to point to the actual app and try to point to it with my nginx server, I get a failure.

Does anyone know what's wrong with these instructions (or have any ideas what I could be doing wrong)?

The AWS deployment documentation is lacking. I can't get anything useful from there. Tearing my hair out and ready to use heroku.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good tutorial here:
[Setup a Ruby on Rails, Passenger, Nginx running on an AWS EC2 with RDS.](http://blog.slowb.ro/2013/06/24/howto-setup-a-ruby-on-rails-passenger-nginx-running-on-an-aws-ec2-with-rds/)